# how to apply a class function to replace NaN for mean within a subset of pandas df columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, machine-learning

The class is composed of a set of attributes and functions including:

Attributes:

- df : a `pandas` dataframe.
- numerical_feature_names: df columns with a numeric value.
- label_column_names: df string columns to be grouped.

Functions:

- `mean(nums)`: takes a list of numbers as input and returns the mean
- `fill_na(df, numerical_feature_names, label_columns)`: takes class attributes as inputs and returns a transformed df.

And here's the class:

```
class PLUMBER():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        ################# attributes ################
        
        self.df=df

        # specify label and numerical features names:
        
        self.numerical_feature_names=numerical_feature_names
        self.label_column_names=label_column_names
        
   
    #####################  mean  ##############################
    
    def mean(self, nums):
        
        total=0.0
        
        for num in nums:
            total=total+num
            
        return total/len(nums)
    

   ############ fill the numerical features ##################
   
    def fill_na(self, df, numerical_feature_names, label_column_names):
        
        # declaring parameters:
        df=self.df
        numerical_feature_names=self.numerical_feature_names
        label_column_names=self.label_column_names
        
        # now replacing NaN with group mean
        
        for numerical_feature_name in numerical_feature_names:
            
            df[numerical_feature_name]=df.groupby([label_column_names]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(self.mean(x)))
        
            
        return df
```

When trying to apply it to a pandas df:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    
    # initialize class
    plumber=PLUMBER()
    
    # replace NaN with group mean
    df=plumber.fill_na(df=df, numerical_feature_names=numerical_feature_names, label_column_names=label_column_names)
```

The next error arises:

> ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

### data and class parameters

```
import pandas as pd

d={'month': ['01/01/2020', '01/02/2020', '01/03/2020', '01/01/2020', '01/02/2020', '01/03/2020'], 
   'country': ['Japan', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'Poland', 'Poland', 'Poland'], 
   'level':['A01', 'A01', 'A01', 'A00','A00', 'A00'],
   'job title':['Insights Manager', 'Insights Manager', 'Insights Manager', 'Sales Director', 'Sales Director', 'Sales Director'],
   'number':[np.nan, 450, 299, np.nan, 19, 29],
   'age':[np.nan, 30, 28, np.nan, 29, 18]}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)


# headers
column_names=df.columns.values.tolist()
column_names= [column_name.strip() for column_name in column_names]


# label_column_names (to be grouped)
label_column_names=['country', 'level', 'job title']


# numerical_features:
numerical_feature_names = [x for x in column_names if x not in label_column_names]
numerical_feature_names.remove('month')
```

How could I change the class in order to get the transformed df (i.e. the one that replaces `np.nan` with it's group mean)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the error is because `label_column_names` is already a `list`, so in the `groupby` you don't need the `[]` around it. so it should be `df.groupby(label_column_names)...` instead of `df.groupby([label_column_names])...`

Now, to actually solve you problem, in the function `fill_na` of your class, replace the loop `for` (you don't need it actually) by

```
df[numerical_feature_names] = (
    df[numerical_feature_names]
      .fillna(
          df.groupby(label_column_names)
            [numerical_feature_names].transform('mean')
      )
)
```

in which you `fillna` the columns `numerical_feature_names` by the result of the `groupy.tranform` with the `mean` of these columns

Comment: Thanks for the observations @Ben.T!, additionally, in order to call mean function from the class, is it possible to apply `lambda` inside `transform()` or is it better to just call `'mean'` inside it ?

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez sure you can use `transform(lambda x: x.mean())`, but it is possible that using `transform('mean')` is cythonized so faster than the same result with `lambda`. it is hard to test, but if you have big dataframes, it can show some time difference to calculate the result

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez so the problem with your version of `mean` does not handle well the `nan` (at least not for the use you want to) hence the result of `self.mean` will always be `nan` if any `nan` in the group. so a quick fix to use your version is in the loop `for num in nums: `, do `if num == num: total=total+num` (it is one way to not sum the `nan`s values. then doing `transform(lambda x: self.mean(x))` should work